# External APFS ecnrypted volume cannot be mount, error 49218

Tags: disk-utility, apfs, diskutil

I accidentally unplugged the cable of an external disk while it was mounted on the system, but not in a copy or read operations. I use APFS encrypted partition on that disk

After I reattached it to the Mac, it could no longer be mounted. The "Disk Utility" application, when I try to mount it, says: Could not mount "photos". (com.apple.DiskManagement.disenter error 49218.)

I also read this https://matt.sh/apfs-object-map-free-recovery but it seems not my scenario.

I don't know what to do anymore and obviously I don't want to delete the entire content because I don't have a recent backup of all the data

If i try to use "First Aid" on APFS partition i will get this error:

```
Running First Aid on “photos” (disk5s1)

Checking file system and repairing if necessary and if possible.
Volume is already unmounted.
Performing fsck_apfs -y -x /dev/rdisk5s1
Checking the container superblock.
error: (oid 0x401) nr: invalid o_oid (0x6836a7)
error: (oid 0x401) nr: invalid o_type (0x80000003, expected 0x80000011)
error: verification/reading of the nx_reaper object failed: Illegal byte sequence
warning: checkpoint 6 (xid 24054) failed consistency check
error: (oid 0x401) nr: invalid o_oid (0x6837a4)
error: (oid 0x401) nr: invalid o_type (0x80000003, expected 0x80000011)
error: verification/reading of the nx_reaper object failed: Illegal byte sequence
warning: checkpoint 3 (xid 24053) failed consistency check
Checking the checkpoint with transaction ID 24052.
Checking the space manager.
warning: (oid 0x6eb5) cib: invalid o_cksum (0x0)
error: (oid 0x6eb5) cib: found zeroed-out block
error: failed to read spaceman cib 3 at address 0x6eb5
Space manager is invalid.
The volume /dev/rdisk5s1 could not be verified completely.
File system check exit code is 8.
Restoring the original state found as unmounted.
File system verify or repair failed. : (-69845)

Operation failed…
```

If i try to use "First Aid" on APFS container i will get this error:

```
Running First Aid on “Container disk5”
Some APFS cryptographic state information was unexpectedly unavailable. : (-69461)
Operation failed…
```

This is the `diskutil list output`:

```
/dev/disk4 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *4.0 TB     disk4
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk4s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk5         4.0 TB     disk4s2

/dev/disk5 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +4.0 TB     disk5
                                 Physical Store disk4s2
   1:                APFS Volume photos                  2.3 TB     disk5s1
```

And this is the `gpt -r show disk4`

```
       start        size  index  contents
           0           1         PMBR
           1           1         Pri GPT header
           2          32         Pri GPT table
          34           6
          40      409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
      409640  7813627488      2  GPT part - 7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  7814037128           7
  7814037135          32         Sec GPT table
  7814037167           1         Sec GPT header
```

Comment: Contrary to your assumption that it *wasn’t* in a copy or read operation, it may have been *writing* something (which is more critical). I would start with some data recovery software like [Disk Drill](https://www.cleverfiles.com/data-recovery-software.html). Do you have a backup?  Given that it’s encrypted, you may not be able to access the data.